# AWS Aurora Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Received backend message CopyData while expecting CommandCompleteMessage

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, amazon-aurora

I'm using Entity Framework Core and I have the following code that works fine on my local Postgresql db and on an AWS Postgresql Instance.

```
_dbContext.SomeTable.UpdateRange(existingItems);
await _dbContext.SomeTable.AddRangeAsync(newItems);
return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When I go to use it on an AWS Aurora PostgreSQL Regional Cluster it fails with the error:

`Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Received backend message CopyData while expecting CommandCompleteMessage.`

I can create, update and delete single items but this is happening when I'm trying to create >400k items.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened. I changed

`await _dbContext.SomeTable.AddRangeAsync(newItems);`

to

`_dbContext.SomeTable.AddRange(newItems);`

and it worked. Maybe that fixed it or a redeployment did something.